# ParticleSystem, performance behind the technique on batching with different materials

Tags: unity, performance, particles, batching

I found that guide:
https://thinhhb.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/unity3d-optimization-make-atlas-textures-for-particlesystem-reduce-drawcall-why-not/ which is quite clever.

As far as I know, we can't batch `ParticleSystems` with different materials, for example:

- A star (Particles/Additive)
- A smoke (Particles/Additive)

give 2 draw calls.

The guide points, that we can use a `TextureSheet` trick to achieve batching of different graphics on multiple `ParticleSystems` like that:

1. We create a spritesheet manually and cut it in Unity's SpriteEditor into a grid, and create a material:

[image]

2. Then, we create our `ParticleSystems` and attach generated sprites into `Texture Sheet Animation Module`:

[image]

And here the magic happens. They batch.

My question is, **what is the overhead behind this**? Is the `TextureSheetModule` expensive?

If I have 15 different sprites, their `ParticleSystems` create 15 batches, which is quite expensive on mobile.

Is it wise, to move to TextureSheet and save these 14 batches?

Comment: This sounds like something you can measure for yourself, on your target hardware, with your real assets, to get an answer far more trustworthy than any internet hearsay us randos might spout. ;) Set up a test scene that pushes your particle rendering to its limits without the atlas trick, then another identical scene but using the atlas trick. Try them both on your device and compare their speed and quality.